# How to filter properties in JSON YQL request?

Tags: json, yql

I'm using Yahoo Query Language (YQL) to retrieve JSON from a web service that does not support CORS and to filter the properties of each response object so that each of these objects in the response JSON contains only the properties I need.

The JSON returned from the web service looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {},
        {},
        ...
    ]
}
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
select results from json where url="..."
```

This returns the `results` property array. How do I modify the "select" query or some other part of the command to select only certain properties in each result object in the `results` array? I'm having trouble finding this out from the [documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should set the query to `"results.name, results.number"`.

Let's see an example that requests some placeholder JSON (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts):

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  ...
]
```

In this example the root is an array and we can filter properties that each object of the array has with this YQL query:

```
select json.userId, json.title from json where url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
```

This gives this JSON response:

```
      "results": {
       "json": [
        {
         "json": {
          "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
          "userId": "1"
         }
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Hey Eric, how would you do this if the array is not the root value in the JSON returned from the web service but is the property of an object (where that object is the root)?

Comment: I thought this was what I needed Eric, but I realized I missed something. I edited the question to clarify what I need.

Comment: I actually figured this out. Your answer helped though. You still get the bounty. I will edit your answer with the correct query for my case: `"results.name, results.number"`